# Apex Set the value of a Picklist - Issue

Tags: apex, trigger

I am setting a value of a picklist based on conditions. My code works however when setting the value there are now two duplicate values in the picklist.

```
Object__c myObject = new Object__c 
(
      picklist__c = 'my value'
);
    insert myObject ;
```

My Value now shows up twice.... Why and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Do you have an existing picklist value entry whose label is 'my value' but which has a different API name? Otherwise, can you be more specific about what you mean by the value showing up twice?

Comment: The value ('my value') already exists in the picklist. I just want to set the value to 'my value'

Comment: OK, so can you edit your question to clarify (and be very specific - you can include debug logs, error messages verbatim, or even screenshots) what the issue is? I may be slow this morning, but I don't follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think  you need to Restrict 
picklist to the values defined in the value set

in object>view field>picklist >edit